# Registering GRAPH32.OCX in Windows 10

Tags: vb6-migration

I have a VB6 `.exe` I want to run in Windows 10. I have the `graph32.ocx`, `gsw32.dll`, and `gswdll32.dll` files in `sysWoW64`. Running `regsvr32` on `graph32.ocx` results in `the module graph32.ocx failed to load`.

I moved them all to `system32` with the same result. Running the `.exe` results in the error `graphs32.ocx or one of its dependencies is not correctly registered`. I tried registering in PowerShell as an administrator.

Comment: I suspect it has dependent modules which are not present.

Comment: improved formatting

Comment: Are you running `regsvr32` as admin?

Comment: I once did troubleshooting on an install where regsvr32 failed cryptically. It turned out that a dependency of the component was missing. Putting the dependency in place fixed the error.

Answer (score 2):

From VB6DEP.INI:

```
[Graph32.ocx]
Dest=$(WinSysPath)
Register=$(DLLSelfRegister)
Uses1=MFC40.dll
Uses2=gsw32.exe
Uses3=gswdll32.dll
```

You have not mentioned MFC40.DLL. Be sure it is present in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing all files in both directories; even **SysWow64** as **System32**, you must registered only  **`.ocx`** that exists is in **system32**.